How to Solve a System of Equations Described by a Recursively Block Circulant Matrix
I want to solve a system of equations given by $M\vec{x}=\vec{z}$ efficiently with the fast Fourier transform (FFT), where $M$ is recursively block circulant (I'm not sure if that is the right terminology). For example, let
$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
0.9749  &0.00806 &0.00629 &0.00245 &0.00565 &0.0026  &0.00004 &0.00001\\
0.00806 &0.9749  &0.00245 &0.00629 &0.0026  &0.00565 &0.00001 &0.00004\\
0.00629 &0.00245 &0.9749  &0.00806 &0.00004 &0.00001 &0.00565 &0.0026\\
0.00245 &0.00629 &0.00806 &0.9749  &0.00001 &0.00004 &0.0026  &0.00565\\
0.00565 &0.0026  &0.00004 &0.00001 &0.9749  &0.00806 &0.00629 &0.00245\\
0.0026  &0.00565 &0.00001 &0.00004 &0.00806 &0.9749  &0.00245 &0.00629\\
0.00004 &0.00001 &0.00565 &0.0026  &0.00629 &0.00245 &0.9749  &0.00806\\
0.00001 &0.00004 &0.0026  &0.00565 &0.00245 &0.00629 &0.00806 &0.9749 
\end{bmatrix}
$
and
$\vec{z}=\begin{bmatrix}0.9749 &0.00806 &0.00629 &0.00245 &0.00565 &0.0026 &4.0E\text{-}05 &1.0E\text{-}05\end{bmatrix}$. Please note that I am trying to solve much larger systems than this and I can always assume that $M$ is invertible. Let $M_0$ be the first column of $M$. Notice that each column consists of the same elements but rearranged and that $M$ is composed of circulant $2\times2$ matrices and is block-block circulant. If $M$ was circulant, I could solve the system directly through
\begin{align}
\vec{x}=\text{IFFT}\left(\frac{\text{FFT}(\vec z)}{\text{FFT}(M_0)}\right),
\end{align}
where the division is element wise and IFFT is the inverse FFT. Is there a similar formula I can use for my scenario?

Your solution for a circulant matrix takes advantage of the fact that $M\vec{x}$ represents a circular convolution.  You could just factor your block circulant $M$ into $AB$, where $B$ is a circulant matrix, and then apply the deconvolution with FFTs of $B$ and $A^{-1}\vec{z}$.

But I guess at that point, Gaussian elimination with pivoting and back substitution is probably faster.
